# React Highcharts Treemap - customize order of boxes

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I want to use Highcharts Treemap graph in my React app, and I want a specific box/cell to be displayed always at the end, on the left side. regardless of it's size.
How can I do that?

I read there is an option to maybe do so by extending the highchart component, but it's still not clear a. How to do it, in general. b. customize the order, after extending the component.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, you need to create your own custom layout algorithm. The simplest way will be to edit a result created by some default algorithm.

For example, for `stripes` it will be:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype.myCustomAlgorithm = function(parent, children) {
  const result = this.stripes(parent, children);

  let index = 4;
  const width = result[index].width;

  result[index].x = result[index].y = 0;

  while (index > 0) {
    index--;
    result[index].x += width;
  }

  return result;
};
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n6z8d4wc/

---

**Useful thread:** https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39629

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/treemap

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.layoutAlgorithm